# Boolean Search In Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have been trying to run the following boolean query in lucene but it seems to fail. Please help.

(a or b) and c -> works fine

(a AND b) or c -> gives result for a AND b OR c. So a becomes must and b and c becomes should, and the search result is wrong. Where it should work like a, b must be available or c may be available.

Another example:

If you search for "(a AND b)" it will return x results

If you search for "c" it will return y results

If you search for "(a and b) or c" the number of results cannot be less than the larger of x or y. But this is not happening. Please help how should I proceed to implement this?

Comment: does a b and c are actual values which you are searching?

Answer (score 0):

(a AND b) or c gets converted to `(+a +b) c`. What you want is this without parentheses: `+a +b c`.

From a logical perspective, "A and B must occur, C might occur" is equivalent to "A and B must occur." (There is no way to say "might be true" in classical logic.) So you will have difficulty saying `(+a +b) c` in boolean terms. One way you could do it is "(a AND b AND c) or (a AND b)".

Comment: Thanks for your response Xodarap. However, my understanding is, all the documents that has any one <"a AND b"> or <"c">, they all should appear in this boolean search result, which is not happening. 

So from a logical perspective, if A and B occur or incase only C occurs in a document all these documents should be returned in the result-set.

Comment: @ranjit: Have you tried doing it like `(+a +b) c`? That will at least narrow down where the problem is. I think in some query parsers the OR needs to be capitalized, which it isn't in your example - so this could be it.